# Getting Log4j2 to use json as logformat

Tags: json, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to get jetty 9.4.14 to log as json to stdout istead of the default org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog. To debug this I run jetty from the demo-base directory with `java -jar ../start.jar`.

I have

- ran `java -jar ../start.jar --add-to-start=logging-log4j2`
- ran `java -jar ../start.jar --add-to-start=ext`
- added jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar and jackson-core-2.9.8.jar to ./lib/ext

If just change loglevel in ./resources/log4j2.xml from "info" to "warning" I see that I only get warning logging to stdout, so the log4j2.xml is read.

When I try to add a new appender with JsonLayout to this file, I see that the org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog logging is used insted of log4j2.

I see this when I add the appender "console2" bellow:

```
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>xxx %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Console>

    <Console name="console2" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
          <JsonLayout></JsonLayout>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
```

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: @joakim-erdfelt Thanks for getting involved by editing my post. I have solved this issue for log4j2 in general by adding a JsonLayout appender. My problem now is that this solution does not seems to work with Jetty.

Comment: Did you `--add-to-start=ext` at any point?

Comment: @joakim-erdfelt Thank you for answering! Yes, I doubled checked and I had already done that: `INFO  : ext already enabled by [${jetty.base}/start.d/ext.ini]`
Thank you in advance for any ideas or tips to how to debug this further!

Comment: I reproduced this issue on jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429. Thank you in advance for any tips or suggestions!